# pulling int out of string to do concatenation

Tags: excel, concatenation, excel-2013, vba

I am using excel 2013 and I am trying to combine a variable containing a string to a portion of another variable containing a string. The portion I need however would be an integer and I would like the leading zeros removed.

So for example I have

```
LName = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(OCR, Sheets("Whitelist").Range("Whitelist"), 3, False)
```

This variable will be someone's last name.
I also have

```
OCR = Right(Left(UserIn, 3), 2) & Left(Right(UserIn, 11), 9)
```

This will be the person member ID it will look something like this DC000123456.
OCR will always be 11 char long and the first two will always be letters with the last nine always being numbers starting with an unknown number of 0's.

I am wanting to make a variable called concat that would be the Last name then space and the numbers from their id with the leading 0's.

I have tried

```
Concat = Lname &" "&Right(OCR, 9)
Concat = Lname &" "&Cint(Right(OCR, 9))
Concat = Lname &" "&Cstr(Cint(Right(OCR, 9)))
```

All of these give errors.

I was wanting to remove the leading zeros. Sorry forgot to include example of end result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't get if you want to keep or remove the zeros in front of the ID.

Given this:

```
LName = "Matteo"
OCR = "DC000123456"
```

If you want to keep them:

```
Concat = LName & " " & Right(OCR, 9)
Debug.Print Concat
>>> Matteo 000123456
```

If you want to remove them:

```
Concat = LName & " " & CDbl(Right(OCR, 9))
Debug.Print Concat
>>> Matteo 123456
```

*note: need to use the function `CDbl`, your `CInt` would give an Overflow because the ID number is larger than the allowed size of `Integer`

Comment: Perfect Thank you!

Comment: Although I thought Integer could hold -2,147,483,648 through 2,147,483,647 and since I am only looking at a 9 digit number that would be in that range I thought.

Comment: @ChadPortman you get confused with "Long Integers" (in VBA, declared as "Long"). The "Short Integer" (in VBA, declared as "Integer") can hold around 32,000 (check this for more details: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_(computer_science)). The function "CInt()" returns a short integer, in your case you were hence overflowing the stack.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.